# Error 500 AJAX, Laravel y JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax, laravel-5

Al intentar enviar un formulario cuyo contenido únicamente es un documento de excel me regresa el mensaje "Ha ocurrido un error" que se encuentra dentro de la parte Fail de mi Js, revisando la consola en Google y Firefox e visto que me regresa el error 500, supuse que podría tratarse de la ruta asi que fui a verificar que mi ruta estuviera bien, después de eso supuse que podría ser mi codigo de php pero el problema es que nunca entra en mi codigo php, esto lo supongo debido a que programe un mensaje dentro del codigo para imprimir lo que tuviera mi request y ese mensaje nunca se imprime, ya revise la documentacion parecida o de preguntas similares a esta y en la mayoria de casos el problema es un error de sintaxis en el Ajax o en php. Pero aparentemente esa no es mi situación o cuando menos eso creo

Codigo de AJAX

```
function confirmarCarga(e){
confirm(e, function(){
    cargarArchivo(e);
});
```

}

function cargarArchivo(e){

```
$(e).hide();
$('#espere').show();
$('#alertaError').hide();
$('#alertaErrorEtiqueta').hide();
var token=$('[name=_token]').val();
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append('request', $('#formularioCargarArchivo').serialize());
datos.append('_token', token);
datos.append('_method','POST');
$.each(archivos, function(key, value){
    datos.append(key, value);
});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url+'/cargar',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data:datos,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(function(respuesta){
    $('[id^=alerta').hide();
    if (respuesta['status']) {
        $('[id^=alertaExito]').show(500);
        $('#alertaExitoEtiqueta').html(respuesta['msg']);
    }else{
        $('#alertaError').show(500)
        $('#alertaErrorEtiqueta').show(500);
        $('#alertaErrorEtiqueta').html(respuesta['msg']);
        if (respuesta.datos['tipoError']==2) {
            var erroresHTML='<div style="color: #FFF; background-color: #A94442; border-radius: 10px">CADENAERRORES</div><hr>';
            $('#alertaErrorLista').empty();
            $.each(respuesta['datos']['erroresArray'], function(llave,valor){
                $('#alertaErrorLista').append(erroresHTML.replace('CADENAERRORES', valor));
            });
            $('#alertaErrorLista').show(500)
        }
    }
    $('#espere').hide();
    $(e).show();
}).fail(function(respuesta){

    $('#alertaError').show(500);
    $('#alertaErrorEtiqueta').show(500);
    $('#alertaErrorEtiqueta').html('Ha ocurrido un error.');
    $('#espere').hide();
    $(e).show();
    console.log('FAIL');
    console.log(respuesta);
});
```

}

function confirmarCarga esta para hacer que se ejecute el envió del formulario después de que sea aceptado el envió y la otra funcion es donde paso la información a la ruta de mi función php

El Codigo de PHP

```
public function archivoRegistrarNeumaticos(Request $request){
    // post_max_size => 128M
    // upload_max_filesize => 128M
    // max_execution_time => ¿?
    // max_execution_time => 30

    Debugbar::addMessage('request', 'mylabel');
    Debugbar::info($request);

    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

    try {

    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {

        return json_encode([
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => 'Se ha producido un error en el proceso de registro.',
            'datos' => ['tipoError' => 1]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Por cuestiones de tamaño del codigo solo muestro a grandes rasgos a donde direcciona la url y la parte que mencionaba en la que muestro lo que trae el request

Mi codigo de rutas

```
Route::post('/cargar', 'Controller@archivoRegistrarNeumaticos');
```

y finalmente mi codigo de HTML donde esta mi formulario

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/cargar') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;" id="formularioCargarArchivo">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">                                            
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" name="excel" required id="excel">
                                <label for="excel"><small>(Formatos admitidos: ".xls" y ".xlsx")</small></label><br>
                                <br><br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" confirmar="¿Está seguro que desea subir este archivo para ser procesado?" onclick="confirmarCarga(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmacion" id="filtrar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span>&nbsp;<strong>Subir</strong></button>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="background-color: #449D44; color: #FFF; border: 2px solid #00263E; border-radius: 5px;" hidden title="Esto puede tardar varios minutos" id="espere">
                                    <label>Espere...</label>
                                </div>
                                <br><br><br><br>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Y esto es lo que ocurre cuando lo envio 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que me muestra la consola 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien no sabría cual es la solucion ya intente de todas las formas que encontré y la única que me falta es configurar el servidor para que dure mas el tiempo de espera porque según algunas fuentes mi problema podría ser que se agota el tiempo y por eso recibo el error 500

Comment: Por favor agrega los mensajes de error que se almacenaron en la carpeta de logs de laravel

Comment: No se ha generado ningún mensaje en el archivo log, de hecho lo eliminé para con la finalidad de que se generará uno más actual únicamente con la información de ese error y no a actualizado nada

Comment: Aún así puedo mostrarte lo que me arrojo el último log y tú me dices si tiene algo que ver aunque debido a las líneas de código que marca no creo que tenga nada que ver con el código de esta parte

Comment: [El status 500 "Error Interno del Servidor", es un código de estado HTTP muy general que significa que algo salió mal en el servidor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). Si no hay nada en los logs de laravel, revisa los logs del servidor (apache/nginx...) y los de PHP. También puedes checkar si los logs de laravel se están escribiendo para otras excepciones (si tiene permiso el servidor). La excepción se debe estar registrando en algún archivo, si no es Laravel, posiblemente PHP o el server

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas si revise los logs pero no había ningún rastro de lo que necesitaba, al final la solución que yo encontré fue modificar el tiempo de espera del servidor, esto porque al parecer los archivos de Excel que se estaban subiendo eran demasiado grandes que excedían el tiempo de espera programado tanto en el código de php como en el servidor.